# Don't have the reputation to add an electric-vehicle or EV tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Would someone with a better reputation add one of these, please?

Comment: please post a link to the questions you think needs the [electric-vehicle] tag. (I don't have the rep to create tags either, but whoever does will need to know where to add it.)

Comment: Done. http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/696/how-to-convert-a-gasoline-powered-vehicle-to-all-electric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the tag to the question as requested.