# Are electric cars on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, topics

We've determined that small engines are on topic.  Also, that Remote Control cars are off topic.  However, with the advent of the Tesla, the Ford Focus Electric, the Chevrolet Volt, etc., one has to ask, Are these cars on topic here?  I almost thought of putting a proposal on Area 51 for electronic cars and RC devices, but thought I'd hear out your thoughts about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [electric-vehicle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicle) tag has been around [since 2011](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/81/4152), so I'd suggest it's been on topic since the beginning.There are (as of this writ) [10 questions on the main site](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicle) which are tagged by [electric-vehicle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicle)

In my eyes, it's directly on topic. It doesn't have to be powered by gasoline or diesel to be on topic here! Just has to be a motor vehicle of some sort ... or some kind of engine related gobble-d-gook. It's all good.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, electric vehicles should be on-topic.

After all, hybrids have been on-topic here for a while, full electric is just the next step in development.

They are motor vehicles that carry people - it is just that the motor is electric rather than internal combustion.

There are many features of electric vehicles that are common to internal combustion vehicles so there is overlap.

Comment: Heck, to my pedantic way of thinking they are **more** on topic, as they are actually *motor* vehicles as opposed to *engine* vehicles…